# PHP whenever i call a $var with time() the value changes

Tags: php, time, session-timeout

**PHP 5.4**

I want to have a `start_time` & `end_time`

`end_time` should have `start_time + 5`

the problem is every time i refresh the page, the times change

how can i get `end_time` to NOT change?

sample code:

```
// Set timeout period in seconds
$_SESSION['inactive_amount'] = 5;
$inactive = $_SESSION['inactive_amount'];

$_SESSION['start_time'] = time();
$start_time = $_SESSION['start_time'];

$_SESSION['end_time'] = $start_time + $inactive;

echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION, true), "</pre>";
```

output 1:

```
Array
(
    [inactive_amount] => 5
    [start_time] => 1423701080
    [end_time] => 1423701085
)
```

output 2 [refresh]:

```
Array
(
    [inactive_amount] => 5
    [start_time] => 1423701098
    [end_time] => 1423701103
)
```

`[end_time]` changes, so it never reaches initial time that was set with `[start_time] + 5 seconds`

the question is simple (for someone who knows), i guess when dealing with any type of time, how can you store it somewhere so the value does not change after it's set? i wrote it like this because it will be used for more than just a session, i have multiple places that i need to compare times.

***NOTE:** i know i could store the `start_time + 5` value in db, then retrieve it again to populate the var, **BUT** i want to do this without a db.

Comment: check if $_SESSION['end_time'] already exists, if it does dont overwrite it

Comment: your start time changes each time you refresh the page.and your end time has relation with start time so it will change as well.

Comment: @Dagon .. Thanks you hit it on the head, using the code below, just switching it up a lil.. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['start_time'])) {
    $_SESSION['start_time'] = time();
}
```

This will prevent your session time from being updated every time you refresh the page. Once its set, it will not be set to the session variable again and again on each page refresh. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank You.. you were close, it was the answer i needed.. kinda.  
    if(!isset($_SESSION['end_time'])) {  
        $_SESSION['end_time'] = $start_time + $inactive;  
    }  

its the `end_time` that i want to make sure is not set, if it is dont increment... (NOT the `start_time`).. +1 for helping